# how to clear gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-3.5

I want to clear my gridview. I have 2 GridViews and Has Select Button On It. on Selecting this button that item goes into the second gridview. now the question is how should i clear the second grid view. I am trying the clear method but clear method is not found in my visual studio..

Answer (score 16):

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
```

or

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
```

Comment: Just one more thing need to share with you guyz. If you go by dataGridView1.DataSource = null;. Then your pageIndex of GridView will not reset to 0, It will always set to your selected pageIndex.

Comment: the Rows.Clear should really be removed from this answer. The question and tags specificially concern  asp:gridviews, not datagridviews

Answer (score 12):

```
gridview.DataSource = null;
//rebind to gridview
gridview.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the Gridview to an empty list.

Binding it to 'null' like Patrick Kafka mentioned should work - unless you have some column requirements (I'm mentioning it because I have a tendancy to plug in javascript into my gridviews and unless you specify those columns in the markup, they won't be generated and it will cause errors in the js. (This is also relevant to those getting errors after doing Columns.Clear )

In a case like that (as well as in all other cases), you can simply bind the gridview to a new instance (or empty instance) of your datasource. (Below example for a gridview bound to a datatable - it could be bound to `new List<T>()` as well).

```
grdiview1.DataSource = new DataTable();
grdiview1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and here is how I resolved it:

1: GridView unlike DataGrid does not have Rows.Clear() method.

2: If like my  my Case GridView binds to a DataSet(call it MyDataSet) to get data then:

```
MyDataSet.Rows.Clear();
//And Bind again,
MyGrid.DataSource=MyDataSet;
MyGrid.DataBind;
```

Note: Using MyGrid.DataSource = null; completely destroys MyGrid structure which includes the header fields.

Answer (score -1):

dataGridView1.Columns.Clear(); //this clears the entire Gridview

Comment: That command does not work n my case. No sure why. This one does as suggested above: gridview.DataSource = null;
// Rebind to gridview.
gridview.DataBind();

Answer (score -3):

Simply add the following c# code to clear the GridView:-

> gridView.Rows.Clear();

Comment: There is no Gridview.Rows.Clear() method available

Comment: There is indeed that method, but I prefer to use DataSource = null;

Comment: My appologies, it's supposed to be Columns.Clear()